# Getting IPGlobalProperties with VB.net on a UWP application

Tags: vb.net, networking, windows-10-universal

I am writing a very simple Universal Windows application with VB in Visual Studio 2017.
The application should gave basic network information to the user, so I wanted to collect the data using `IPGlobalProperties` and print – as a first example – the `DomainName` in a TextBlock called `textDomain`

```
Dim NetworkProperties As NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties
NetworkProperties = NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties
textDomain.Text = NetworkProperties.DomainName
```

While the properties are correctly assigned int the first two lines of code, the third line result in the error `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'`
I tried the same code on a classic Windows application and it works as intended, so is this operation not supported by Universal applications?
If yes, what is the method I should use to get the same information about network?

Thanks for any help you might provide

Luca

Comment: Can you please explain the -1 ? A down-vote with no explanation I think is in no one interest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, [`IPGlobalProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) class is not supported in uwp app. Since.NET for UWP apps provides a set of managed types that you can use to create Universal Windows Platform apps, but not the all. Details please reference [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx). [`System.Net`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185489.aspx) namespace can be used in uwp app but `IPGlobalProperties` cannot.

Secondly you can find equivalent or similar APIs in uwp app. For example you can also find a [`NetworkInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation) in uwp which is belong to `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` namespace. But invoking the methods of this class is not the same way with the [`System.Net.NetworkInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation(v=vs.110).aspx)  namespace.

If you want to get the computer name or domain name as `IPGlobalProperties` did, you may invoke the [`GetHostNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation_GetHostNames) method. Code as follows:

```
Imports Windows.Networking.Connectivity
''' <summary>
''' An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
''' </summary>
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Private Sub btngetinfo_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)  
        Dim hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
        textDomain.Text = hostNames.First.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  As additional reference for anyone interested in this topic, I would also point the user to the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.hostname where `HostName` class is explained.